# Encontrar valores SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Preciso de ajuda, tenho uma tabela de e-commerce chamada tabelaproduto, preciso listar o nome do produto, valor de venda, produtos com estoque entre 20 e 30 e que qualquer parte do nome do produto tenha a letra "A", e preciso ordenar nessa ordem, começando pelo nome. Como não manjo de SQL fiz:

```
SELECT FROM tabelaproduto nomeprod LIKE(%A), valorvenda, WHERE estoqueprod BETWEEN 20 and 30
```

Está correto? Pois preciso alterar o nome do produto para "promocao" o valor da venda para 10% do valor atual, e o estoque do produto de chave "3" para 10 unidades, quando rodo o primeiro comando, ele aparece tudo nulo.

Obrigado =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ideia está lá, mas a sintaxe não está completamente correcta. Uma alternativa seria assim:

```
SELECT nomeprod,
       valorvenda
  FROM tabelaproduto 
 WHERE nomeprod LIKE '%A%'           
   AND estoqueprod BETWEEN 20 and 30
 ORDER BY nomeprod, valorvenda, estoqueprod
```

A instrução

```
SELECT nomeprod,
       valorvenda
```

indica qual a informação que pretende seleccionar da base de dados. Se quiser, por exemplo, listar também o estoque, basta alterar para:

```
    SELECT nomeprod,
           valorvenda,
           estoqueprod
```

A segunda parte indica qual a origem (tabela) onde a informação está guardada, e quais os filtros que devem ser aplicados. Quando não existe cláusula WHERE, todos os registos/linhas da tabela serão listados:

```
  FROM tabelaproduto      
 WHERE nomeprod LIKE '%A%'           -- produtos cujo nome contém pelo menos um 'A'
   AND estoqueprod BETWEEN 20 and 30 -- e que tenham estoque entre 20 e 30
```

Finalmente, a cláusula ORDER BY, especifica qual a ordem pela qual os resultados deverão ser apresentados, neste caso, os resultados serão ordenados por nome, valor de venda e finalmente por quantidade/estoque.

```
ORDER BY nomeprod, valorvenda, estoqueprod
```

Se quiser, por exemplo, ordenar por nome e depois por estoque disponível, basta apenas alterar a ordem das colunas, assim:

```
ORDER BY nomeprod, estoqueprod
```

Comment: Cara, me ajudou bastante, nossa, me deu um Norte. Estava completamente perdido, eu tinha +- uma noção, mas sua explicação foi fantastica. Agora pra eu alterar o produto, e o preço, basta isso?

`Update tabelaproduto set 
Nomeprod = ‘Promoção’
Valorvenda = valorvenda+(valorvenda*10/100)
Where produtocod = 8;`

Comment: Exacto, isso será suficiente para actualizar o produto.

Comment: Cara, obrigado mesmo, me ajudou bastante o/

Comment: De nada, @GeraldoSilva